# Large alpha coherent state almost eigenstate of creation operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra, coherent-states

I’m surveying the relation between quantum and classical mechanics. My interest is how a quantum coherent state approaches a classical state when the wave becomes bigger.

Regarding this, I have a calculation result that a large $\alpha$ coherent state is almost an eigenstate of the creation operator with the eigenvalue $\alpha ^{\ast }$( It is an eigenstate of the anihilation operator is well known, though.)

is this correct?

The commutation relation:

$$aa^{+}-a^{+}a=1$$

Next, setting the error vector $| k\rangle$,

$$a^{+}| \alpha \rangle = \alpha ^{\ast }| \alpha \rangle +| k\rangle $$

Now, the squared length of each term is,

LHS:
$$\begin{aligned} \langle \alpha \left| aa^{+}\right| \alpha \rangle =\langle \alpha \left| a^{+}a\right| \alpha \rangle +1=\left| \alpha \right| ^{2}+1 \end{aligned}$$

RHS:
$$\langle \alpha \left| \alpha \alpha ^{\ast }\right| \alpha \rangle = | \alpha |^{2} $$

$$\langle k| k \rangle =( \langle \alpha \left| a- \alpha\langle\alpha \right| ) | ( a^{+}| \alpha \rangle -\alpha ^{\ast }| \alpha \rangle ) =(\left| \alpha \right| ^{2}+1)+\left| \alpha \right| ^{2}-\left| \alpha \right| ^{2}-\left| \alpha \right| ^{2} =1 $$

Summarizing this,

When $\alpha$ is large, the length of the error vector k can be negligible with respect to the other terms. So, when $\alpha$ is large, a coherent state is almost an eigenstate of the creation operator.

——————————————————————————————————————————-

Thanks for replies and clarifying!

Comment: Indeed, $|\alpha\rangle$ and $|k\rangle$ are normalized and mutually orthogonal. The action of the creation operator complex scales the first, by a large magnitude, if you choose, and adds an   "error" equal to the second.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: $a^\dagger$ has no non-singular eigenvectors. W.l.o.g., take *α* real. Then, in the large  *α*  limit, the coherent state is an eigenvector of both *a* and $a^\dagger$, and thus their commutator, $\infty\times  0 =1$. Is this what you mean?